# run zenity from php

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec, zenity

In my local ubuntu machine I would like to popup a message with zenity from a php script.
so i put:

```
exec("zenity --info --text 'TEST' " );
```

but nothing happens.
The same line works fine when typed in a shell.
I tried adding the --display parameter with different combinations but no luck.

Was thinking maybe exec commands need to be enabled somehow for safety reasons?
Or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is Safe Mode off? If not check if [safe_mode_exec_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir) is configured correctly.

Comment: Yes, safe mode is off. exec('ls'); runs fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this from the terminal (php cli) or mod_php? This seems to work fine on my machine on the terminal. If this is a server box it is highly likely that php is hardened.  Check your `php.ini`.

If you're trying to use zenity from a php script executed by a browser, this is a wholly different story. As the php interpreter will be run as a different user, you need to make sure that this user is allowed to run programs on your X session. Check `xauth` and read up on how Xorg authenticates sessions etc., but make sure you pay attention to the possibly security implications that may result from any changes you make.

Comment: php -r 'exec("zenity --info --text TEST " );' runs fine from the terminal, but not in a script ran by a browser. Server settings are install defaults. Will try to descypher which php.ini line is messing with me. THanks!

Comment: php.ini looks fine. other commands (ls) run fine as exec from a browser. still stump by zenity.

Comment: Well, that's a bit more complex. I've updated the answer; hopefully it'll steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, I found that xhost local:www-data does the trick, but it looks like it opens a big hole in the system. Will keep it off until I find a more targeted way to authorize this script. Thanks for your help.